# How to check if user defined input is unique in a vector of an Object type?

Tags: java, vector, unique, primary-key

I am doing a school project based on a stock control system. I want the prducts to have their product id as their primary key. Upon input of the product id I want to traverse the vector inorder to check whether that id is already existent; If this is the case, then the user is prompted to enter a new, unique id. I wrote the following code:

```
String chkpid = "[0-9]{4}[P]";
valid = false;
                matchid = false;
                do{
                    System.out.println("Enter Product ID (4-digit code followed by the Letter P): ");
                    pid = sc.next();
                    if(pid.matches(chkpid)){
                        for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i ++){
                            st = temp.elementAt(i);
                            if(pid.equals(st.getPid()))
                                matchid = true;
                            else
                                matchid = false;
                        }
                        if(matchid == true){
                            valid = false;
                            System.out.println ("Product ID already in use. Please Enter an uncommon ID.");
                        }else
                            valid = true;
                    }else
                        System.out.println ("Invalid Product ID Format.");
                }while(valid != true);

                Stock s1 = new Stock(name, qty, cost, pid);
                temp.add(s1);
                added = true;
                System.out.println ("Product was Added Succesfully!");
                System.out.println ();
            }
```

This seems to work fine, but I noticed that it only stops the user to enter an id which is the same as the previous element. For example if there are 2 products with different id's in the vector, and the user is inputting a new product with the same id as the 1st element, it is accepted and added to the vector (which obviously is wrong!). However, if the input id is equal to the id of the 2nd element, the user is prompted to enter a new one (thus doing what it is supposed to do).  How can I fix this? P.S I am new to java, so sorry for any stupid mistakes!
I have gone through this step by step and I cannot seem to find where my logic is faulty!

Moreover, are there any better ways to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
for(int i = 0; i < temp.size() && matchid == false; i ++){
      st = temp.elementAt(i);
      if(pid.equals(st.getPid()))
           matchid = true;
       else
           matchid = false;
}
```

You need to stop the loop when you find a similar id to keep the right value in your boolean matchid

For a better way off implementation, check `Vector.contains(Object o)`. But you'll need to create a Stock object with the new pid to compare two Stock object

EDIT :

```
public static void main(String[] main){
    int valueToCheck = 85;

    Vector<Integer> list = new Vector<Integer>();

    list.add(5);
    list.add(15);
    list.add(85);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(145);

    boolean matchid = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < list.size() && matchid == false){
          if(list.elementAt(i) == valueToCheck)
               matchid = true;
           else
               matchid = false;

          ++i;
    }

    System.out.println(i + " : " + matchid);
}
```

My output is `3 : true` meaning that I exit the loop when I found the value 85
and `5 : false` with and other value

Comment: That did not work. It will always display that the id is already existent in the vector even though it was not.

Comment: If I use the `Vector.contains(Object o)` method, how can I specifically check for the product id though?

Comment: That strange because when I try this, I exit the for loop with the correct value in matchid. Check the EDIT.
Check out for contains, there are enough example on stackoverflow